# how to GET the SINGLE ROW  with cursor in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

i want to get the row from databas which name = jiten
but is gives error in syntax can anyone tell me what is the right syntax for 
getting the single row
here is my code for database class

```
public void getdata()
{


     Cursor cursor = myDataBase.query("emp", new String[] {"email","name"}, " name='jiten'",new String[]{}, null, null, null);

     Log.e("running", "cursor run");



     if(cursor!=null)
     {

         Log.e("running", "curosr is not null");
     while(cursor.moveToFirst())
     {

         Log.e("running", "curosr while loop enter");

         String temp =  (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(email)));
             String temp2 =(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(name)));
        Log.e("running", "id  email" +temp+ " name"+temp2);

    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the selectionArgs

```
   public Cursor query (String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy, String limit)
```

> You may include ?s in selection, which will be replaced by the values
>   from selectionArgs, in order that they appear in the selection. The
>   values will be bound as Strings.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

in your case it would be:

```
 Cursor cursor = myDataBase.query("emp", new String[] {"email","name"}, "name=?",new String[]{"jiten"}, null, null, null);
```